# how to use native views in Nativescript

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, telerik, nativescript

I'm using NativeScript with Angular2 and typescript.
Trying to add native elements this way :

html :

```
<StackLayout #camview class="camView">
</StackLayout>
```

typescript :

```
@ViewChild("camview") camview: ElementRef;


    constructor() 
    {


    }

    ngOnInit() 
    {
        alert("AA");
        var label = new UILabel(CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200));
        label.text = "Hello World again";
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        this.camview.nativeElement.addSubview(label);
        alert("BB");
    }
```

I'm not sure wheter an elementRef.nativeElement.addSubView is supposed to work but nothing appear on the resulting screen.
What's even more surprising is how alert AA works but not alert BB, like if code interpretation was interupted between them

I don't have any errors or complains, the app continues to run and I'm able to navigate away and back to this page.

I tried to force an error by misspelling UILabel to UILabeel, but it does not produce an error as I would have expected.. its just the same behaviour.

Am I supposed to tell nativescript these are native elements/mehods somehow?

Comment: What is the native element behind "camview". Most layout have methods like addChild() which can be used like `myGrid.addChild(titleLabel)`

Comment: Perhaps try as this.camview.nativeElement.ios.addSubview(label);

Comment: Have you found a solution to this one?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours, I realized how to do it.

XML:

```
<StackLayout #stackLayout></StackLayout>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('stackLayout') stackLayout: ElementRef<StackLayout>;

addButton() {
   this.androidButton = new android.widget.Button(applicationModule.android.context);
   this.androidButton.setText("Some button text");
   this.stackLayout.nativeElement.nativeView.addView(this.androidButton);
}
```